# SQL Rows are not deleted from table when using where not exists and select distinct subquery

Tags: sql-server, subquery, where-clause, not-exists

I am fairly new to SQL and have not been able to find what I'm doing wrong. I am trying to delete rows that have matching fields in 2 specific columns with other rows in the same table, for a temporary table so that only one row remains with the same ID and Year AND so that the row that remains is the one with the MAX date for those ID's in that Year.

```
My table: 
ID                 Year                  Date
---------------------------------------------------- 
1                  2017                 01/05/2017 
1                  2017                 11/17/2017 
1                  2017                 08/07/2017 
1                  2016                 03/22/2017 
1                  2016                 04/01/2017 
2                  2017                 03/12/2017 
2                  2016                 02/03/2016 
2                  2016                 04/19/2016
```

Desired results:

```
ID                 Year                  Date
---------------------------------------------------- 
1                  2017                 11/17/2017 
1                  2016                 04/01/2016 
2                  2017                 03/12/2017 
2                  2016                 04/19/2016
```

What I have:

```
DELETE FROM #Temp 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT DISTINCT
                t1.ID, 
                t1.Year
        FROM #Temp AS t1, 
             #Temp AS t2
        WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID
        AND t1.Year <> t2.Year 
        GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.Year )
```

When I run it, nothing gets deleted but when I remove the first two lines to test what would be deleted, the results are correct so I'm really confused. I am working on the MAX function but want this part to work first.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I have no idea what could be wrong with it.

Comment: i've removed the MySQL tag because it looks like you are using SQL-server. Based on the #table syntax usage.

Comment: Your exists clause is not correlated to the outer query - it always returns rows and therefore "not exists" is always false. Generally speaking, usage of "distinct" is often an indication that the query is logically flawed. Here is serves no purpose at all. As the others have posted, learn to use windowing functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one other way is to use `row_number()` function to find the duplicate records based on `ID`.. `Year`

```
delete t from
(
    select *, row_number() over (partition by ID, [Year] order by date desc) rn from <table>
) t where t.rn > 1
```

Comment: Thank you!! This worked perfectly! I'm still not sure why mine didn't work but now I know about partitions and using row numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as 
(
    select row_number() over (partition by ID, Year order by date desc) as rn
)
delete * from cte where rn > 1;
```